# ibm.commons error after upgrade to Notes 9

Tags: xpages

I have an XPage app that has been working fine.  I upgraded my client from 8.5.3 FP6 to 9.0.1 FP1, built the database and now receive the following error on the 8.5.3 server console:

HTTP JVM: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/commons/util/io/json/JsonJavaObject.put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

If I rebuild from an 8.5.3 client it runs fine again.

Any suggestions on what I need to do differently using the 9.0.1 Designer client ?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you receive an error if you run the page or when compiling? If its the page can you post the code causing the error?

Comment: The error occurs when running the page.  The error message appears on the server console.  The code is pretty lengthy, and runs fine when built with 8.5.3 client.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code that fails?

Comment: The entire code block is about 150 lines of code.  But I think the following are the pertinent lines:  `JsonJavaObject returnJSON = new JsonJavaObject();  returnJSON.put("success", true);  returnJSON.put("total", userList.size());  jsonList = JsonGenerator.toJson(JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx, returnJSON);'

Comment: Well, for the time being I've downgraded to 8.5.3 client.  When the servers are upgraded then I'll upgrade my client.  Thanks all for the help/suggestions...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried compiling the application to run as an earlier version? There is an option in xsp properties to compile with an earlier version.

Comment: I've tried setting the minimum at the "minimum release required..." and also at 8.5.3 and the same error results.

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile on your Designer, it's a specific problem for your server. Check plugins and additional Java libraries on your server. There might be a conflict.

On your server, extension library is installed? If yes, which version? (ExtLib for 8.5.3 contains IBM Commons jar, so it may be a reason of conflict), OpenNTF Domino API? Social Enabler?

You might also test with a clean Domino installation to determine the root cause.

Comment: I have limited access to the production servers.  I setup a new 9.0.1 server and the build on my 9.0.1 client runs fine on that server, but not on the 8.5.3 server.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I have misunderstood the question. You are trying to compile it on 9 but run on 8.5.3, right? I'm not sure at which version IBM started delivering IBM Commons plugin. I have checked 8.5.3 extension library and seems like it has IBM Commons. Probably, it doesn't exist in 8.5.3 server but it's part of 9.x product. So check extension library version by `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.commons` console command. That's the missing part.